# Problem with m{} in tabular

Tags: tables

Can someone please tell me why if I write this piece of code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage{amsmath, amscd, amsthm, amssymb}

\counterwithin{table}{section}    

\begin{table}[H]
        \centering%
        \footnotesize
        \begin{tabular}{|m{0.10\textwidth}|m{0.10\textwidth}|m{0.15\textwidth}|m{0.20\textwidth}|m{0.10\textwidth}|m{0.10\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            \text{Bernoulli}                                                 &
            $p \in [0,1]$                                                    &
            $\left \{ 0, 1 \right \}$                                        &
            $\begin{aligned} p(0) &= 1 - p \\ p(1) &= p \end{aligned}$       &
            $p$                                                              &
            $p(1 - p)$                                                    \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{}
    \end{table}
```

I obtain this error:

> Illegal character in array args

and the resulting table is like this?

[image]

Comment: You need the array package: `\usepackage{array}`

Comment: In your instance, you need to still load both the [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) *and* [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) packages: `\usepackage{array,float}`

Comment: Thank you very muck guys, think I should have a rest! :)

Comment: Rather than `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}`, do `\usepackage{mathptmx}` or, better yet, `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`, so that math will be in a font compatible with Times.

Comment: Are you sure you want `m` in this case (it will lose the baseline alignment of your expressions) `p` might be better.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, many are missing that caused the errors.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amscd, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{chngcntr,array}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

\counterwithin{table}{section}    
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}|p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.20\textwidth}|p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        \text{Bernoulli}    &     $p \in [0,1]$     &    $\left \{ 0, 1 \right \}$   &
        $\begin{aligned}
        p(0) &= 1 - p \\ 
        p(1) &= p 
        \end{aligned}$    &      $p$                 &     $p(1 - p)$    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
   \label{test}
   \end{table}
Table \ref{test} is displayed above.
 \end{document}
```

Remarks:

1. `chngcntr` package is missing for your `\counterwithin` command.
2. `placeins` is added to bound table with section.
3. `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` are missing.
4. `m{}` needs `array` package, but `p{}` requires no package, so I change it.
5. To have 3 columns, some vertical lines in table setting are redundant.

Comment: The `m{...}` column type requires `array`, not `float`. `float` is only needed fot the `H` placement specifier.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- Ya, you are right. Thanks and corrected accordingly.